# Drupal 8 views - Unformatted list of fields showing in-line (not as expected)

Tags: html, css, drupal-8

I'm still learning Drupal 8, HTML and CSS...

Created a new view of the type: unformatted list of fields of the 'Race' content type.
Page: Row style options (nothing is set to in-line).
I added one field, Title.

I have 10 Races.
When I see the output in preview, I see 10 lines, each with the title displayed (as expected)
When I look at the actual page all these tiles appear in-line (not as expected!)

Looking at the outer div I see it uses the row class.  If I disable display: flex; the lines wrap corectly.

I'm not sure where to go next, is something wrong in my setup, if so could you suggest where to look?

http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss

```
@mixin make-row($gutter: $grid-gutter-width) {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -$gutter / 2;
  margin-left: -$gutter / 2;
}
```

[image: Titles Inline]

Comment: How do you want them to display? 1 event per line? Have you set 'flex' on each of them? What you are seeing is what I would expect. Take a look at [this page about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was related to the themse I am using.
I fixed this by copying this file:
/web/themes/contrib/bootstrap_barrio/templates/views/views-view.html.twig

to my custom theme folder:
/web/themes/barrio_custom/templates/views-view.html.twig

Then making this change:

```
  {% if rows %}
    <div class="view-content row">
      {{ rows }}
    </div>
  {% elseif empty %}
    <div class="view-empty">
      {{ empty }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

updated to remove the row class:

```
  {% if rows %}
    <div class="view-content">
      {{ rows }}
    </div>
  {% elseif empty %}
    <div class="view-empty">
      {{ empty }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```